# What should I do if I find a question with the answer as an edit?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I was looking at questions where I might be able to improve the quality, and I found a question, [Using mscomm ActiveX with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778299/using-mscomm-activex-with-qt-solved), that had the answer edited into the question. Is it OK for me to take the edit answer and post it as an actual answer, and then revert/undo the edit that added the solution? It seems iffy because I don't want to take credit for someone else's answer, but I don't want to leave it the way it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would do is to first suggest to the OP to write that as an answer.
If he doesn't do that, then (after X days) I would edit the question to remove the answer, and write that part as answer, giving credit to the OP. If the answer can be made better, I would change it, and if I am be able, I would first verify it is the correct answer.